# To get url of Web page

Tags: html

Want send url of my website. How can I get the url of it. I made up the html page with few tags which contains only must tags and tables. But now I want to send this Web page to my senior through social networking site. To check out the needs and corrections. So please help me to get url of Web page

Comment: your website does not have a url unless you own a domain for that.
If you have made it on localhost , i.e your pc only, then directly send html file as a attachment in mail.

Comment: Well first off, you're going to need to purchase a domain and a server.

Answer (score 0):

your webpage isn't on the net yet so it doesn't have an url, but you can send the folder of your html page to someone so they can see it if you still wish to.